# Is it possible to exclude only French tweets from a Twitter advanced search engine?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

To find only tweets in French, i use:

```
find this words lang:fr
```

But what if I want to exclude only French from the results and find all the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very easy, just put a minus `-` before the `lang:fr` operator to exclude it :-)

```
find this words -lang:fr
```

If i'm not mistaken all of [Twitter's Advanced Search Operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/search-operators), like `filter:`, `near:`, `within:`, `include:` and many more, can be negated to exclude results corresponding to the specific operator.